# How to increment individual element in an array in firestore for flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

[image]
This is how my data look like.

I'm able to use FieldValue.increment(1) to update individual fields but is there a way to use FieldValue.increment(1) for specific individual elements in the array? Thanks in advance!

I tried using the following code:

```
firestore.collection('test').doc('I1raMaJArb1sWXWqQErE')
          .update({
        'rating.0': FieldValue.increment(1),
      });
```

But the whole rating became empty as seen
[image]

Comment: Can you please provide your code snippets for better understanding?

Comment: ok I've just added the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `FieldValue.increment()` if the field is part of the array. The value of the field inside the array is fixed. The best way to update or edit the field that part of an array is to read the entire document, modify the data in memory and update the field back into the document.

Comment: Ok, got it. Thank you.